# Android: Play network video by TextureView

Tags: android

I want to play a network video by TextureView, but I found some devices cannot normally display. There is only audio without image. So is there anybody has solution for this case? By the way, I have turned on hardware accelerate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you can use this open source:https://github.com/google/grafika, to test your media source, if it display correctly in all your phone, maybe it is your code error, so learn the grafika code to find what is wrong.

Comment: I can make sure that my code is correct, since it can work on some device. But I don't know why some Android TV cannot display normally with black screen.